# Botbuilder adaptive dialog storing user input

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using previews of the botbuilder adaptive dialog to gather some user info. I want to store this information in SQL. So my question is how can I gather the info from the "Property" in the textinput?

```
new TextInput
            {
                Prompt = new ActivityTemplate(question.Text),
                Property = "user.userProfile" + question.Id
            }
```

Comment: SQL is a querying language, but I presume you mean you want to store the information in a database. Does your DBMS have some kind of REST API you can call via HTTP?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes of course. I wrote an api to handle the database.

Comment: Is Giang Nguyen's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CodeAction or HttpRequest to call your api to store the information

Use this to make HTTP requests to any endpoint.

```
new HttpRequest()
{
    // Set response from the http request to turn.httpResponse property in memory.
    ResultProperty = "turn.httpResponse",
    Method = HttpRequest.HttpMethod.POST,
    Headers = new Dictionary<string,string> (), /* request header */
    Body = JToken.FromObject(new
                                {
                                    data = "@{user.userProfile" + question.Id + "}",
                                    another = "@{user.another}"
                                })                                   /* request body */
});
```

Code Action

```
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CodeActionSampleFn(DialogContext dc, System.Object options)
        {
            var userState = JObject.FromObject(dc.GetState().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "user").Value);
    //Get your data here
            var data = userState.Value<JObject>("userProfile" + question.Id);
    // call your API by HttpClient
//...
    return dc.ContinueDialogAsync();
        }
```

Check out more detail here
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/docs/recognizers-rules-steps-reference.md#HttpRequest

Comment: How do I get the data contained in a property after the fact though?

Comment: Do you mean the turn.httpResponse? Try to print your response and you will see the format of the response after HttpRequest ` new SendActivity("@{turn.httpResponse}")`

Comment: no how do I get the response from the text input and post that?

Comment: Update the detail, check it out

Comment: Thanks I'll be trying this!

Answer (score 1):

You can see examples of how to access [state properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-dialog-memory-states) all over [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-dialog/adaptive-dialog-prebuilt-memory-states):

```
new SendActivity("Hello, @{user.name}")
```

Comment: How can I access state properties in CodeAction? I tried ${user.name}, but it does not return the correct value from memory scope. Those two links you provided show 404 Page Not Found error, can you please give updated links?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62924035/2122672