# How to convert from xml to json within Adaptive dialog HttpRequest?

Tags: c#, json, xml, botframework, chatbot

I am new to Bot Framework and C#. I am building a chatbot using Adaptive Dialog with the Core Flight Booking Template ([adaptive-dialog/03.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/adaptive-dialog/03.core-bot)). I want to make an API call to get the weather information. This OpenWeather API can return data in JSON, XML, or HTML format. When the response is in JSON format, it is easy to access the key-value pairs. But when the response is in XML format, everything will be converted into a string and saved as 'content' in the response, I have to convert it into either JSON or a Dictionary so that I can access the detailed information. And I need to save the API response as a property in the dialog for later reference.

I know we can use the following code to convert from XML to JSON, but the question is how to do it in the adaptive dialog. I tried to include the following code in the HttpRequest block but got the error *"XmlDocument is a type, which is not valid in the given context."* It seems like you cannot add your own customized codes in the adaptive dialog, what you can do is only using what the template can offer, but right now the HttpRequest class does not have an option for parsing XML response. Can anyone please give me some guidance on this? Thanks!

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Codes to make the HttpRequest in the adaptive dialog:

```
new IfCondition()
{
    Condition = "conversation.Id != null",
    Actions = new List<Dialog>()
    {
        new HttpRequest()
        {
            Url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=Detroit&mode=xml&appid=appid={your api key}",
            ResultProperty = "dialog.httpResponse",
            Method = HttpRequest.HttpMethod.GET,
            ResponseType = HttpRequest.ResponseTypes.Json
        },
        new Send Activity("${dialog.httpResponse}"),
        new Send Activity("${dialog.httpResponse.content}")
    }
}
```

The following shows what the HttpRequest response looks like. The OpenWeather API response (XML format) is converted into a string as the value of 'content'.

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": 
    {
        "Server": "openresty",
        "Date": "Tue, 14 Jul 2020 18:57:41 GMT",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "X-Cache-Key": "/data/2.5/weather?mode=xml&q=detroit",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST"
    },
    "content": "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n
                <current>
                    <city id="4990729" name="Detroit">
                        <coord lon="-83.05" lat="42.33"></coord> 
                        <country>US</country>
                        <timezone>-14400</timezone>
                        <sun rise="2020-07-14T10:08:16" set="2020-07-15T01:07:33"></sun>
                    </city>
                    <temperature value="301.11" min="300.15" max="302.59" unit="kelvin"></temperature>
                    <feels_like value="301.1" unit="kelvin"></feels_like> 
                    <humidity value="44" unit="%"></humidity>
                    <pressure value="1019" unit="hPa"></pressure>
                    <wind>
                        <speed value="2.1" unit="m/s" name="Light breeze"></speed>
                        <gusts></gusts>
                        <direction></direction>
                    </wind>
                    <clouds value="75" name="broken clouds"></clouds>
                    <visibility value="16093"></visibility>
                    <precipitation mode="no"></precipitation>
                    <weather number="803" value="broken clouds" icon="04d"></weather>
                    <lastupdate value="2020-07-14T18:57:41"></lastupdate> 
               </current>"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you be willing to edit your post so that your JSON is a formatted code block instead of a screenshot? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @KyleDelaney. I have updated the question according to your suggestion, the screenshot of the JSON response was replaced by a formatted code block.

Comment: You said "This OpenWeather API can return data in JSON, XML, or HTML format." So why don't you just get the data in JSON format to begin with? Can you link to the API docs?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Kyle. Actually I am just using the OpenWeather API as an example here, due to the privacy concerns I cannot disclose the actual API I need to call. For the actual API there is only XML formatted response, otherwise I would be able to just use the JSON response directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a code action.

```
new IfCondition()
{
    Condition = "conversation.Id != null",
    Actions = new List<Dialog>()
    {
        new HttpRequest()
        {
            Url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=Detroit&mode=xml&appid=appid={your api key}",
            ResultProperty = "dialog.httpResponse",
            Method = HttpRequest.HttpMethod.GET,
            ResponseType = HttpRequest.ResponseTypes.Json
        },
        new CodeAction(async (dc, options) =>
        {
            var xml = dc.State.GetValue("dialog.httpResponse.content", () => "<root></root>");
            var doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

            dc.State.SetValue("dialog.json", json);

            return await dc.EndDialogAsync();
        }),
        new SendActivity("${dialog.json}"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kyle! I was trying to use `CodeAction` but did not know how to access the `dialog.httpResponse` inside the custom code. The above code you gave works great.  I added one more line to parse json so that the key-value pairs can be directly accessed from `dialog.json`. After `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);`, I added `var json_final = JObject.Parse(json);` and then set `json_final` as the value of `dialog.json` so that the weather information can be obtained using `"${dialog.json.current.weather}"`.